# Enable fileinfo extension

Tags: php, centos

It's on a Centos 7, PHP 5.5.38

I thought the fileinfo was enabled by default, but phpinfo() shows below:

```
'./configure' **'--disable-fileinfo'** '--disable-opcache' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

So how do I enable this fileinfo?

The current extension folder doesn't have fileinfo.so, so I don't know what I need to do now to enable this.

Comment: That depends on how you installed PHP. If you installed it through your package manager then you need to use your package manager to find the appropriate package in your loaded repository for the fileinfo extension for PHP. If you compiled PHP yourself then you need to recompile with the extension enabled or compile the extension separately and loaded as a shared extension.

Comment: I remember it was installed as part of the WHM/Cpanel Installation.

Comment: Well, then it becomes a support question for the people that support WHM/Cpanel. In any case, this question isn't on-topic for StackOverflow, because it is not a programming question. It may be more suited for ServerFault if you care enough to ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem, using WHM/Cpanel recompile Apache and PHP

https://www.opensource-excellence.com/blog/item/464-how-to-install-fileinfo-in-whm.html